# Bundle has invalid content in tables.sql:_create table YYY

Tags: liferay

I'm trying to deploy a service builder module on my Liferay portal. But I'm getting the error below.

Could this be caused because I already have that table on my database? The table was created manually as part of an older project, and now I'm trying to reuse that existing table.

Thanks in advance.

> 2019-07-24 12:09:47.770 ERROR [pipe-start
>   998][com_liferay_portal_upgrade_impl:97] Invocation to listener threw
>   exception  com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: Bundle
>   com.xxxx.xxxx.service_1.0.0 [998] has invalid
>   content in tables.sql:_create table dbo.*news (*  id_ INTEGER not null
>   primary key,_ title VARCHAR(75) null,_    push_notification
>   BOOLEAN,_ date_time VARCHAR(75) null,_    short_description VARCHAR(75)
>   null,_    long_description VARCHAR(75) null,_ picture VARCHAR(75)
>   null,_    type_ VARCHAR(75) null,_    tag VARCHAR(75) null_); [Sanitized]
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ParentModuleApplicationContextExtender$InitialUpgradeStep.upgrade(ParentModuleApplicationContextExtender.java:220)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.upgrade.internal.executor.UpgradeExecutor$UpgradeInfosRunnable.run(UpgradeExecutor.java:159)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.output.stream.container.internal.OutputStreamContainerFactoryTrackerImpl.runWithSwappedLog(OutputStreamContainerFactoryTrackerImpl.java:119)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.upgrade.internal.executor.UpgradeExecutor.executeUpgradeInfos(UpgradeExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.upgrade.internal.executor.UpgradeExecutor.execute(UpgradeExecutor.java:87)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.upgrade.internal.release.osgi.commands.ReleaseManagerOSGiCommands$UpgradeInfoServiceTrackerMapListener.keyEmitted(ReleaseManagerOSGiCommands.java:485)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.upgrade.internal.release.osgi.commands.ReleaseManagerOSGiCommands$UpgradeInfoServiceTrackerMapListener.keyEmitted(ReleaseManagerOSGiCommands.java:474)
>     at
>   com.liferay.osgi.service.tracker.collections.internal.map.ServiceTrackerMapImpl$DefaultEmitter.emit(ServiceTrackerMapImpl.java:222)
>     at
>   com.liferay.osgi.service.tracker.collections.map.PropertyServiceReferenceMapper.map(PropertyServiceReferenceMapper.java:43)
>     at
>   com.liferay.osgi.service.tracker.collections.internal.map.ServiceTrackerMapImpl$ServiceReferenceServiceTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ServiceTrackerMapImpl.java:260)
>     at
>   com.liferay.osgi.service.tracker.collections.internal.map.ServiceTrackerMapImpl$ServiceReferenceServiceTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ServiceTrackerMapImpl.java:248)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:943)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:903)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:891)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:469)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:487)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:1004)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ParentModuleApplicationContextExtender$ParentModuleApplicationContextExtension._processInitialUpgrade(ParentModuleApplicationContextExtender.java:613)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ParentModuleApplicationContextExtender$ParentModuleApplicationContextExtension.start(ParentModuleApplicationContextExtender.java:571)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:488)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:1)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:129)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:191)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:467)     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:447)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.console.commands.EquinoxCommandProvider.start(EquinoxCommandProvider.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:91)
>     at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:599)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:526)
>     at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:415)
>     at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.doCall(Pipe.java:416)     at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:229)    at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:59)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: DBO   at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(JDBCUtil.java:376)  at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(JDBCUtil.java:247)  at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(JDBCStatement.java:1817)    at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(JDBCStatement.java:208)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyStatement.java:117)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyStatement.java)
>     at com.liferay.portal.dao.db.BaseDB.runSQL(BaseDB.java:294)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.dao.db.BaseDB.runSQL(BaseDB.java:264)  at
>   com.liferay.portal.dao.db.BaseDB.runSQLTemplateString(BaseDB.java:452)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.dao.db.BaseDB.runSQLTemplateString(BaseDB.java:509)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ParentModuleApplicationContextExtender$InitialUpgradeStep.upgrade(ParentModuleApplicationContextExtender.java:216)
>     ... 59 more Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token:
>   DBO   at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Error.java:101)    at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(ParserBase.java:815)    at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserBase.checkIsIrregularCharInIdentifier(ParserBase.java:335)
>     at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.checkIsSchemaObjectName(ParserDQL.java:115)
>     at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readNewSchemaObjectName(ParserDQL.java:5912)
>     at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.compileCreateTable(ParserTable.java:78)   at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreate(ParserDDL.java:156)    at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(ParserCommand.java:236)  at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(ParserCommand.java:91)     at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Session.java:1227)  at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Session.java:1018)     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(JDBCStatement.java:1809)
>     ... 67 more

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the table is already existing is surely the issue. Service builder deployment keep track of the "schema" version that is currently deployed, and if there is none, they create it using the sql script.

In your case, I would suggest

1. renaming or exporting and delete your current table
2. deploying your new service
3. move your data back to the new table created

Once this is done, don’t ever touch that data directly in the database, let your new service handle all future interaction. In fact, it might even be better to import the old data using the service API.